# FreeBSD Bind locks up, only clue -> in6_ifadd: 2001:~ is already configured

Tags: networking, bind, freebsd

I have an issue where my DNS locks up periodically (about twice a day).
All normal and then suddenly denied access to net_if

```
network: error: could not listen on UDP socket: permission denied
```

When you look deeper into the messages logs, the only error since last reboot is

```
Dec 14 13:50:17 r2d2 kernel: in6_ifadd: 2001:19f0:7000:8945:5400:ff:fe05:3dab is already configured
Dec 14 13:59:26 r2d2 kernel: in6_ifadd: 2001:19f0:7000:8945:5400:ff:fe05:3dab is already configured
```

if I restart networking

```
service netif restart
```

networking completely fails and I end up rebooting after numerous attempts to bring it up and then all is back to normal, for about another two or three hours, then same thing.

my rc.conf

```
# service -l|grep net
inetd
netif
netoptions
netwait
[\u@r2d2:/root] # cat /etc/rc.conf
hostname="r2d2.ex-mailer.com"
#ifconfig_vtnet0="dhcp"
sshd_enable="YES"
static_routes=linklocal
route_linklocal="-net 169.254.0.0/16 -interface vtnet0"
crypto_load=YES
cryptodev_load=YES
aesni_load=YES

gateway_enable="yes"
#ifconfig_vtnet0_ipv6="inet6 2001:19f0:7000:8945:5400:00ff:fe05:3dab prefixlen 64"
ifconfig_vtnet0_alias0="inet6 2001:19f0:7000:8945:5400:0001:0001:0002 prefixlen 64"
ifconfig_vtnet0_alias0="inet6 2001:19f0:7000:8945::64 prefixlen 64"
rtsold_enable="YES"
rtsold_flags="-aF"

apache24_enable="YES"
named_enable="YES"
mysql_enable="YES"
dovecot_enable="YES"
sendmail_enable="NO"
sendmail_submit_enable="NO"
sendmail_outbound_enable="NO"
sendmail_msp_queue_enable="NO"
postfix_enable="YES"
apache24_enable="YES"
saslauthd_enable="YES"
spamd_enable="YES"
clamav_freshclam_enable="YES"
clamav_clamd_enable="YES"
maiad_enable="YES"
mailman_enable="YES"
milteropendkim_enable="YES"
milteropendkim_uid="opendkim"
mailgraph_enable="YES"
swapfile="/usr/swap0"

pf_enable="NO"
pf_rules="/home/pf.conf"
pflog_enable="YES"
pflog_logfile="/var/log/pflog"

firewall_enable="NO"
firewall_type="open"
```

This started after a full system update the other day.

where else can I look to begin to debug this or look for a solution?

Comment: Why are you using rtsold (SLAAC) while setting a static address. I have a feeling that BIND is using a SLAAC address to bind() to, and when that address expires it can't listen() on it anymore.

The other message simply states that FreeBSD is trying to add the IP address to the interface (SLAAC) but for some reason it is not being recognised as "configured". See: https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-net/2014-June/039008.html